# Determining quotient of a module using only presentation matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given an $n \times n$ presentation matrix $A$ (with entries from $R[t]$) for an $R[t]$-module $V$, so $V\cong (R[t])^n / A (R[t])^n$, is there a nice or easy-ish way to compute $V/p(t)$? In my particular example $n = 16$ but a more general method is appreciated.

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix over $R$, or can it have polynomials too, as entries?

Comment: @Berci $A$ can (and does) have polynomial entries; edited question.